# Asymptotic formula for sums of powers of reciprocals of primes

Tags: number-theory

Is there an explicit asymptotic formula, in terms of $\alpha$, for the expression
$$\displaystyle \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p^\alpha}$$
for $0 < \alpha < 1$?

The case $\alpha = 1$ is supplied by Merten's Theorem:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} \sim \log \log x.$$

Comment: You can estimate the series by an integral like [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx)

Comment: $p_n\approx n\ln n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prime number theorem says that the $n$-th prime is $p_n \sim n \log n$.  So your sum becomes
$$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1}{p^{\alpha}} \sim \sum_{n : p_n \le x}\frac{1}{n^\alpha (\log n)^\alpha}\sim\sum_{n=2}^{x/ \log x}\frac{1}{n^\alpha (\log n)^\alpha} \sim \int_{2}^{x/\log x}\frac{dn}{n^{\alpha}(\log n)^\alpha} \sim \frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)(\log n)^{\alpha}}\Bigg\vert_{2}^{x/\log x}\sim\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)(\log x)^{1-\alpha}(\log\log x)^{\alpha}}
$$
for $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Comment: $$ \frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)(\log n)^{\alpha}}\Bigg\vert_{2}^{x/\log x}\sim \frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{(1-\alpha)\log x}$$